# No output displayed

Tags: python-2.7

There is no output displayed with my basic programe, can you please help.

```
class className:

    def createName(self,name):
        self.name=name

    def displayName(self):
        return self.name


if __name__ == '__main__':

    test=className()
    test.createName('John')
    test.displayName()
```

Comment: You're not printing anything out.  You're retrieving a value, but you're not printing it out.

Comment: use 'print' => print test.displayName()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should print the value:

```
print (test.displayName())
```

That should output the value.